# Twilio test phone number is not working

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform, cloud, twilio

I am using twilio on parse cloud for user phone authentication with my iPhone app, but when I call the cloud code for sending code message from the test phone number (+15005550006), it gives me an error saying "The From phone number +15005550006 is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number or short code for your account. (Code: 141, Version: 1.7.5)"

My cloud code so far is:

```
var twilioAccountSid = 'my-account-sid'; 
var twilioAuthToken = 'my-auth-token';
var twilioPhoneNumber = '+15005550006';
var secretPasswordToken = '12345';

var language = "en";

var twilio = require('twilio')(twilioAccountSid, twilioAuthToken);

Parse.Cloud.define("sendCode", function(req, res) {
    var phoneNumber = req.params.number;
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(/\D/g, '');

    if (!phoneNumber || (phoneNumber.length != 10 && phoneNumber.length != 11)) return res.error('Invalid Parameters');
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.equalTo('username', phoneNumber + "");
    query.first().then(function(result) {
        var min = 1000; var max = 9999;
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

        if (result) {
            result.setPassword(secretPasswordToken + num);
            result.set("language", language);
            result.save().then(function() {
                return sendCodeSms(phoneNumber, num, language);
            }).then(function() {
                res.success();
            }, function(err) {
                res.error(err);
            });
        } else {
            var user = new Parse.User();
            user.setUsername(phoneNumber);
            user.setPassword(secretPasswordToken + num);
            user.set("language", language);
            user.setACL({});
            user.save().then(function(a) {
                return sendCodeSms(phoneNumber, num, language);
            }).then(function() {
                res.success();
            }, function(err) {
                res.error(err);
            });
        }
    }, function (err) {
        res.error(err);
    });
});

Parse.Cloud.define("logIn", function(req, res) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    var phoneNumber = req.params.phoneNumber;
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(/\D/g, '');

    if (phoneNumber && req.params.codeEntry) {
        Parse.User.logIn(phoneNumber, secretPasswordToken + req.params.codeEntry).then(function (user) {
            res.success(user._sessionToken);
        }, function (err) {
            res.error(err);
        });
    } else {
        res.error('Invalid parameters.');
    }
});

function sendCodeSms(phoneNumber, code, language) {

    var promise = new Parse.Promise();
    twilio.sendSms({
        to: '+91' + phoneNumber,//.replace(/\D/g, ''),
        from: twilioPhoneNumber,//.replace(/\D/g, ''),
        body: 'Your login code for AnyPhone is ' + code
    }, function(err, responseData) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            promise.reject(err.message);
        } else {
            promise.resolve();
        }
    });
    return promise;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Twilio developer evangelist here. That telephone number is valid, but doesn't seem to be a Twilio number. Where did you copy it from? Please check that there aren't any typos on it.

Comment: I copied it from their blog/documentation. It didn't work for me at all so I switched to Nexmo.

Comment: The number you copied is just a sample number. You need to use a number you own.

Comment: Okay, so there is no test number for free. right?

Comment: When you create your trial account you are given one free test number, which although slightly limited, would work fine for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, but there is no such trial number given.

Comment: Twilio user here, they definitely provide a test number, because I used it myself. Twilio is a pretty powerful platform. I use it for anonymous calls and texts between my users and have had great success with it. Never heard of Nexmo. If you run in to a lot of trouble with it, I'd consider switching back to Twilio. Awesome guys.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get twilioAccountSid and twilioAuthToken?

If from https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/getting-started -> "Get API Credentials", but it does not work for me too.

I got from https://www.twilio.com/user/account/voice/dev-tools/test-credentials and it works for me now.